# How to use IPv6 proxy with php curl?

Tags: php, curl, proxy, ipv6

I am trying to use IPv6 proxy with php CURL:

```
    self::$rCh = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( self::$rCh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( self::$rCh, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30 );
    curl_setopt( self::$rCh, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, self::iTimeout );
    curl_setopt( self::$rCh, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; 
Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13' );
    curl_setopt( self::$rCh, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
    curl_setopt( self::$rCh, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( self::$rCh, CURLOPT_POST, 0 ); 
    curl_setopt( self::$rCh, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'a123:b123:123::1' );
    curl_setopt( self::$rCh, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 12345 );
    $sPage = curl_exec( self::$rCh );
```

But what i get is this error:
Couldn't resolve proxy 'a123'

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "[]":

```
curl_setopt( self::$rCh, CURLOPT_PROXY, '[a123:b123:123::1]' );
```